# Is it mathematically possible to solve this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\vec{y}= \log{\frac{\vec{x}}{\sqrt[3]{x_1 \cdot x_2 \cdot x_3}}}$$

Here, $x$ and $y$ are always vectors of length 8 and all elements of $x$ are greater than $0$. $x_1$, $x_2$, and $x_3$ are the first three elements of $x$; is it mathematically possible to determine these elements given you only have $y$?  I should note that $x$ is known for some of my dataset, which could be useful to find a solution for the other portion of the data where $x$ is unknown.

Comment: What is the logarithm of a vector ?

Comment: Apologies, I'm not used to this notation. For example, the first element of y would be calculated as $y_1 = \log\frac{x_1}{\sqrt[3]{x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3}}$ and the second element would be $y_2 = \log\frac{x_2}{\sqrt[3]{x_1\cdot x_2\cdot x_3}}$ and so forth

Comment: If $\vec{x}$ satisfies the above conditions, then $k\cdot \vec{x}$ satisfies them as well for any $k >0$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$x_i=\sqrt[3]{x_1x_2x_3}\,e^{y_i}.$$

Multiplying the equations for $i=1,2,3$, you get the compatibility condition

$$1=e^{y_1+y_2+y_3}.$$ Without it, no solution exists.

Then using  ratios,

$$x_2=x_1e^{y_2-y_1}$$
$$x_3=x_1e^{y_3-y_1}$$ and you are free to choose $x_1$.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are asking is that for vectors:
$$y=\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\end{pmatrix},x=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}$$
then is there a way to calculate:
$$y=\begin{pmatrix}\log\frac{x_1}{(\prod x)^{1/3}}\\\log\frac{x_2}{(\prod x)^{1/3}}\\\log\frac{x_3}{(\prod x)^{1/3}}\end{pmatrix}$$
notice that:
$$y_1+y_2+y_3=\log(x_1x_2x_3)-3\log(\prod x)^{1/3}=\log(\prod x)-\log(\prod x)=0$$
and since we know $|y|=8$ we have the system:
$$y_1+y_2+y_3=0$$
$$y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2=64$$

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow, but $y_i$ can be less than $0$

Comment: Where do you get $y_i>0$?

Comment: Oh it's all elements of x not x and y